# Cannot install playsound; "Python was not found" error

Tags: python, pip

I have tried the following:

```
pip install playsound,
-m pip install playsound,
python -m pip install playsound,
python3 -m pip install playsound
```

The Output:

```
PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\phython> python3 -m pip install playsound
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

After Disabling:

```
PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\phython> python -m pip install playsound 
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,   
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python -m pip install playsound
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: im using vscode btw

Comment: It looks like you didn't install Python. How did you try to install it or verify that it is installed? Or did you do that at all? The installer is available at https://www.python.org/downloads/. Did you make sure your PATH variable is set correctly? It's telling you to run `python` without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store. Did you try that? If not, why not? If so, what went wrong?

Comment: Also note that adding clarifying information like "im using vscode btw" can be done by [edit]ing your post rather than adding a comment.

Comment: bro i installed python from the given site and i checked it as well from windows powershell by typing the python--version XD y are u being rude man XD